# Mobile first responsive design

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am currently redoing my css and other stuff thats needed to make my adaptive site to a responsive - until now I designed my site for my laptop and then scaled down and now Im doing from the other side.

I have managed to get the site look ok in 319x480 and now Im gonna see where to make my first breakpoint: exactly how do you go about this? Should I only resize window horizontally and see where a break is needed or should I also do it vertically? From the tutorials Ive seen they always just talking about horizontally, but arent you missing some stuff then?

Also, now it looks good in portrait mode. Lets say I will make a breakpoint at 600px width for portrait and one at 1000px and thats it. Should I then after go back to 319x480 and flip to landscape and expand the site once again and find new breakpoints for landscape mode too?

How are you going about this in a methodical way? I think this is a really cool way to design and I really wanna learn how to do it right.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Your question is very broad here.

Comment: Don't worry about the vertical. How often do you not have to scroll on a desktop? Not very often and virtually never on smaller screens. Focus on the horizontal and do what you said, resize and see at what points need adjustments. Portrait vs landscape is the same difference as resizing the browser horizontally. Some use general smartphone, table and desktop breakpoints but isn't required. Even when using those general breakpoints you'll still find points in between that will need adjustment.

Comment: Best se bootstrap

Comment: Thanks for input guys, Ill definately save some time here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use min-width media queries if you are doing mobile first. Desktop first uses max-width. Concentrate on width rather than vertical height like you were asking, if the browser window height is resized it is usually fine with the scrollbar. You don't want people to have to scroll horizontally usually.

Example:

```
.header-title {
    font-size: 14px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .header-title {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .header-title {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the main breakpoints you can check in browser console. Here you can see, that as a rule, only width changes. Probably, vertical resize won't influence your page that much

Answer (score 0):

In general CSS break points are horizontally because responsive have a "flow" layout. For example, if you have a grid layout with 3 photos side by side and your browser gets too narrow display all of them, the should get stacked on top of one another so the view can scroll through them.

It's always a good idea to test your site at multiple sizes and aspect ratios, especially if you are using fixed/absolute position or calculating heights.